# Is Cannondale Hollowgram 30mm crank spindle symmetrical?

Tags: crankset, cannondale

As per title is Cannondale Hollowgram crank spindle symmetrical? Sure looks like to me, I'm talking about the 109mm x 30mm diameter silver one, although longer ones also seem symmetrical from pictures.

The reason I'm asking is I noticed a writing "non-drive side only" on one side and thought why does it matter if the spindle is perfectly symmetrical, unless it isn't?

I have slight wear on spindle where it previously engaged with BB. Wanted to flip it around for the new installation so the new BB would be engaged with yet pristine surface of spindle and thus hopefully prolong it's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

The older ones were symmetrical but always had the sides marked. Newer ones for Ai etc may be different. The crank you are supposed to detatch for service has changed between l&r over time too.

The spindle shouldn't wear if the bearings are kept good. If wear is suspected on either side, replace the spindle rather than turning it to swap l/r. Safety first or not at all!

——-new info

I found a spindle in my box and of course, it isn’t symmetrical at all. One side has a lip to maintain the position and meaning that the spindle can only be inserted/removed from that one side. If you are happy to swap this around and have measured the protrusion is the same on both sides and won’t change your chainline, then of course it’s OK. But some of the special spindles, like the one for the SRM powermeter, needed to be the right way round.

Comment: Well I suspect the BB bearings weren't replaced in time by previous bike owner, but I'm putting in new BB in my setup. As for wear on the spindle I don't see it as a safety concern, more like not 100% performance and accelerated wear for future. I mean how much would you have to let a crank spindle wear out for it to become unsafe? close to snapping point? not sure that's even possible...